# Select in form react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im new to react and i have a little issue, i am trying to update the my variable : **nom** with the select in my form contact and then do a post request but i cant retrieve this data when im trying to send the request i got a 400 error but when im deleting the select and work with the text area everything works

Can you help me understand where i am wrong please.

This is my code working

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText } from 'reactstrap';



class Create extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      nom: ''
    };
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
alert('Votre parfum favori est : ' + this.state.value);

    e.preventDefault();


    const data = {
      nom: this.state.nom
    };

    axios
      .post('http://localhost:8082/', data)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          nom:'',
        })
        this.props.history.push('/');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error in CreateBook!");
        console.log(err);
      })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      <div className="Create">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
              <br />
              <Link to="/" className="btn btn-outline-warning float-left">
                  Show book List
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
              <h1 className="display-4 text-center">Add book</h1>
              <p className="lead text-center">
                  Create new book
              </p>

              <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div className='form-group'>
                  <input
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='Name'
                    name='nom'
                    className='form-control'
                    value={this.state.nom}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  />
                </div>

              </form>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Create;
```

and this the code i want to replace the actual text area

```
                <label>
          Choisissez votre parfum favori :
          <select value={this.state.nom} onChange={this.onChange}>
            <option value="grapefruit">Pamplemousse</option>
            <option value="lime">Citron vert</option>
            <option value="coconut">Noix de coco</option>
            <option value="mango">Mangue</option>
          </select>
        </label>
```

Comment: What does your response return ? what will be future value of `this.state.nom`?

Comment: i want to be grapefruit or  lime or  coconut or  mango

Comment: Okay then set it's value to that response value.

Comment: @mouk91400 response means that your request was invalid or corrupt in some manner. You would need to debug the request being sent, and check if you are missing any headers/parameters.

Comment: thanks for your reply, what i understand from debogging its when i use the select box the value for nom isnt change so when i do the post request im sending void and in my back side i required the field, i dont know why my variable nom didnt change when i select lime for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the select the name "nom":

```
<select name="nom" value={this.state.nom} onChange={this.onChange}>
```

Comment: i found the solution i had to created a change event ( https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)   
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({nom: event.target.value});
  } and adjusted it with my code thanks you anyway !

Comment: just tried your solution she work too, i waisted 1 hour for a name xD, will be a lesson i guess thanks !